# "Quota error (device dm-*) find_block_dequentry: Quota for id * referenced but not present" messages whenever I boot

Tags: server, dmraid

One week after installation of The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I got server crash.

In log files I don't see any errors so I made photos. One more thing I inserted new ram modules ( before was 4 Gb, now 16 Gb).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I tried to make `memtest` and got:

```
error to small lover memory (0x99100 > 0x8f000)
```

After all i replaced my old ram module but errors there still occurred.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the original RAM around in the slots (if this applies in your situation)? I've seen RAM only work in particular slot configurations. Also, did you make any changes to BIND or amavis prior to the crash?

Comment: i added 2 new domains in BIND but one week ago by hand not from ispconfig.. amavis is untouched

Comment: I did HDD check with smartctl , but everything is OK...

Comment: And i forgot to mention, that system boots normaly.. but screen every 20~ seconds flashes with QUATA ERROR ( u see in first picture)

Comment: Are you mounting a CIFS volume - perhaps via fstab? What I'm finding in my searching is that the 'quota error' seems to be related to CIFS mounts with disk quotas enforced.

Comment: douggro i dont know.... how can i check?

Comment: No i`m not using CIFS :(

Comment: The memtest issue is a known bug -see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/560839

Comment: yes.. but it`s not fix`ed :(

Comment: Are you using any disk quotas for users?

Comment: /dev/mapper/prasyt--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0       1

Comment: yes quata is enabled... i folowed http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p5

Comment: proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
/dev/mapper/prasytojas--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfm t=vfsv0 0 1
/dev/mapper/isw_bjaiaiijih_RAIDAS1 /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/prasytojas--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/.lt/www/clients/client1/web1/log none bind,nobootwait 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/.lt/www/clients/client1/web3/log none bind,nobootwait 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/.lt /www/clients/client1/web4/log none bind,nobootwait 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/.lt /www/clients/client1/web5/log none bind,nobootwait 0 0

Comment: That's probably your problem. Please edit your question to show the contents of /etc/fstab

Comment: I created new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/389600/problem-with-quotacheck-ubuntu-12-04-perfect-server

Comment: Not duplicate two different things

Comment: Are you using a RAID?