# Quota error (device dm-4): find_block_dqentry: Quota for id 107 referenced but not present

Tags: fstab, quota

I have problem with my server. For server configuration I followed http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p5

My screen is flashing every 20 seconds with

```
[ 545.828437] Quota error (device dm-4): find_block_dqentry: Quota for id 107 referenced but not present
[ 545.829017] Quota error (device dm-4): qtree_read_dquot: Can't read quota structure for id 107
```

( I also did photos because cant find thease errors in logs).

[image: photo]

My fstab:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/prasytojas--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0       1
/dev/mapper/isw_bjaiaiijih_RAIDAS1 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/prasytojas--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/aus.lt /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/pra.lt /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/ve.lt /var/www/clients/client1/web4/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/1d.lt /var/www/clients/client1/web5/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yesterday i created http://askubuntu.com/questions/389089/the-perfect-server-ubuntu-12-04-lts-problems. Now i know that this is not RAM problem ( momtest passes without errors). Please hellp :)

Comment: Mabey disable quota? > /dev/mapper/prasytojas--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrjquota=NOquota.user,grpjquota=NOquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0       1

Comment: `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup` to make a backup of your current stab. Then edit `fstab` and remove the `,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv` portion. `sudo mount -a` and see if it throws an error.

Comment: douqqro yes, problem dissapered, but now what to do with quotas :D

Comment: Sadly there is no explanation in the HowTo you used describing the intent or application of enabling quotas. It may be covered in the ISPConfig documentation. If your services are running normally, there's usually little need to enable them except in scenarios where storage capacity is limited based on the number of users utilizing those assets.

Comment: I`ll try if what i will repply my soltion :) douqqro thank you!

Comment: @douggro can you write that as answer?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, just done.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotas:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
```

to make a backup of your current `fstab` file. Then edit `fstab` and remove the `,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv` portion.

```
sudo mount -a
```

to reload the `fstab` entries.

Sadly there is no explanation in the HowTo you used describing the intent or application of enabling quotas. It may be covered in the ISPConfig documentation. If your services are running normally, there's usually little need to enable them except in scenarios where storage capacity is limited based on the number of users utilizing those assets.